# How to set different learning rate for different layer in pytorch?

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, pytorch

I'm doing fine-tuning with pytorch using resnet50 and want to set the learning rate of the last fully connected layer to 10^-3 while the learning rate of other layers be set to 10^-6. I know that I can just follow the method in its document:

```
optim.SGD([{'params': model.base.parameters()},
           {'params': model.classifier.parameters(), 'lr': 1e-3}], 
          lr=1e-2, momentum=0.9)
```

But is there anyway that I do not need to set the parameters layer by layer

Comment: Can you clarify your question.. You would want to set the learning rate of the last fully connected layer to 1e-3 and the rest to 1e-6?? What do you mean by "But is there anyway that I do not need to set the parameters layer by layer?"

Answer (score 1):

You can group layers. If you want to group all linear layers, the best way to do it is use [`modules`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.modules):

```
param_grp = []

for idx, m in enumerate(model.modules()):
    if isinstance(m, nn.Linear):
        param_grp.append(m.weight)
```